# Python, замена CLRFs в JSON

Tags: python, serial

Получаю из `/dev/ttyAMA0` сообщения с помощью такого кода:

```
@app.route('/rmem_memory', methods=['POST'])
def _rmem_memory():
    if 'username' in session:
        cmmd = 'h\r'
        port.write(cmmd.encode('ascii'))
        output = port.read(871)
        d = collections.OrderedDict()
        d['status'] = 200
        d['output'] = output
        return flask_json.dumps(d, sort_keys=False, indent=True)
    return 'nothing'
```

получаю в ответ JSON в таком виде:

```
{
 "status": 200, 
 "output": "h\r\nI2C-SPI-Tools usage:\r\n  v display version of I2C-SPI-Tools\r\n  h print this help\r\n  x reset peripheral ICs\r\n  t print timing\r\nI2C bus:\r\n  l list all slave devices\r\n  r  [ [number of bytes to read]]\r\n      read up to 256 data bytes from specified slave device\r\n  w    [data byte] [...] [data byte]\r\n      write up to 256 data byte to specified slave device\r\n      all values can be integer or hexadecimal\r\n      indicate hexadecimal values with leading \"0x\"\r\n      hexadecimal values are proceeded by \"0x\"\r\n      state the 7-bit version of the slave address\r\n      values in square brackets are optional\r\n  de toggle DE function\r\nSPI bus:\r\n  rw   
 \r\n  mcu  define MCU as SPI Master\r\n  ext  define external source as SPI Master\r\n  am   analyzer mode\r\ntoggle echo?\t^E\r\n>"
}
```

хотелось бы отформатировать правильно, убрать `\r\n` и все в новую строку.

Comment: Внутри строк JSON переносы запрещены по стандарту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d['output'] = output.replace('\r\n', '\n')
```

Comment: Выглядит сомнительно...

Comment: работает не совсем, заменяет \r\n на \n но не форматирует в после \n в новую строку

Comment: Это потому, что я так и не смог понять фраз "и все в новую строку" и "не форматирует в после \n в новую строку", как ни старался. Символ `\n` - это и есть новая строка.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это моя вина, да. Не знал как объяснить. Вот в общем вывод через minicom http://prntscr.com/cc0h1q, в таком формате хотелось бы и в JSON, но вроде  \n не известен JSON

Comment: Аааа, так вы хотите разорвать строку в json-файле переносами? Это нарушение формата, он потом не прочитается. Для этих целей как раз и служит управляющая последовательность `\n`, парсерам json она прекрасно известна.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а тогда почему он дальше и показывает также с `\n` и не переносит строки?

Comment: Кто "он" и что значит "показывает"?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44672/discussion-between-insider-and-sergey-gornostaev).